# Unable to force strictness in tail recursion

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, tail-recursion

I am dealing with memory leaks in my Haskell program and I was able to isolate it to very basic laziness problem in dealing with arrays. I understand what's happening there. First element of the array is computed while the rest produce the delayed computations which consumes the heap. Unfortunately, I was unable to force strictness for the entire array computation.

I tried various combinations of seq, BangPatterns, ($!) without much success.

```hs
import Control.Monad

force x = x `seq` x

loop :: [Int] -> IO ()
loop x = do
  when (head x `mod` 10000000 == 0) $ print x
  let x' = force $ map (+1) x
  loop x'

main = loop $ replicate 200 1
```

The profile with standard profiling options didn't give me any more information than I already know:

```sh
ghc -prof -fprof-auto-calls -rtsopts test.hs
./test +RTS -M300M -p -hc
```

This runs out of memory in the matter of a few seconds.

Comment: What do you think `force x` does that `x` does not do?

Comment: Well, I want to force strict creation of the new list. I have a suspicion that force doesn't do anything here actually. My text editor also says that it's useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
force x = x `seq` x
```

That's useless. `seq` doesn't mean "evaluate this thing now"; it means "evaluate the left thing before returning the result of evaluating the right thing". When they're the same, it does nothing, and your `force` is equivalent to just `id`. Try this instead:

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Monad

loop :: [Int] -> IO ()
loop x = do
  when (head x `mod` 10000000 == 0) $ print x
  let x' = map (+1) x
  loop $!! x'

main = loop $ replicate 200 1
```

That evaluates `x'` and everything in it before `loop x'`, which is useful.

Alternatively, Control.DeepSeq has a `force` function that is useful. Its semantics in this case are "evaluate all of the elements of your list before returning the result of evaluating any of it". If you used its `force` function in place of your own, your original code would otherwise work, since the first line of `loop` does evaluate the beginning of the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Deepseq works. I was looking for something like that.